# Delegate with sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, delegation, tabpanel

I am trying to use delegate to detect when a tab item has been clicked. Here is my view:

```
Ext.define('SenchaPOC.view.Viewport',{
    extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
    xtype: 'tabpanel',

    config:{
        fullscreen: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        items:[{
                    xtype: 'profilepage'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'internaltransferpage'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'accounttrendspage'
                }
        ]
    },
    listeners: {
        delegate: 'tabbar > tab',
        tap: function() {
            console.log("changed");
        }
    }
});
```

It is not working. I think the error is in this line

```
delegate: 'tabbar > tab'
```

Anybody know how to fix this? Also, how can I get the title of the tab that has been changed to?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the 'activeitemchange' event. try with:

```
listeners: {
    activeitemchange: function(that, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        console.log( newValue.getTitle() )
    }
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, this does the same thing I was trying to do. But the error came from something else. please check my answer

Comment: Actually, this is also answering your 2nd question: 'Also, how can I get the title of the tab that has been changed to?'

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I realized that the error was that 'listeners' should be inside 'config'.

```
Ext.define('SenchaPOC.view.Viewport',{
    extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
    xtype: 'tabpanel',

    config:{
        fullscreen: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        items:[{
                    xtype: 'profilepage'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'internaltransferpage'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'accounttrendspage'
                }
        ],
        listeners: {
            delegate: 'tabbar > tab',
            tap: function() {
                console.log("changed");
            }
        }
    }
});
```